# What app can I use to browse photos on my iOS devices from a Mac on the local network?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, wifi, photos

I am trying to figure out if there's an app out there that can let me browse photos from my Mac via wifi.

So I have a

- mac on the local network
- iOS devices on the local network
- 1000s of images on the mac (Aperture/Shared_Folder)

I want

- access to these images on the iOS devices
- slideshows etc

Can't seem to find anything yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because this seems very brief. What are you browsing from. Where are the pictures in the Mac? You only want this function locally?

Comment: So I have a 
- mac on the local network
- iOS devices on the local network
- 1000s of images on the mac (Aperture/Shared_Folder)
- access images on the iOS devices
- slideshows etc

Answer (score 1):

If you have Aperture, you can create libraries without importing the original. I have my photos on different libraries. One on my usual Mac and and a few others on external disks on another Mac. It might be a bit slow but it works

Answer (score 0):

You just need an SMB or AFP file browser app.  I use [FileExplorer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fileexplorer/id499470113?mt=8) to browse network shares from iOS. It will definitely work for your needs.  There is also a free version available